# What is the final velocity of a stone dropped out of a rising balloon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-fall

> A balloon is starting from the ground has been ascending vertically at uniform velocity for 4 sec and a stone let to fall from it reaches the ground in 6 sec. Find the velocity with which the stone hits the ground. ($g= 10 \frac{m}{s^2}$)

The answer given in my book is $42 \frac{m}{s}$ but I got $-60 \frac{m}{s}$ using the equation $v = u + at$.
If my answer is wrong please tell why this equation didn't work.

**Working** :-
 $t = 6 s$
 $u = 0 \frac{m}{s}$ (left fall means stone is released from rest without any push)
 It's under free fall $a = -10\frac{m}{s^2}$
$v = u + at$ 
$v = 0 + (-10)6$
$v = -60 \frac{m}{s}$

Comment: could you please show your complete working?

Comment: Working added in question.

Comment: What is the 'uniform velocity' with which the balloon is moving?

Comment: We  have to assume it as  u and  we get initial velocity of of stone w.r.t ground which is equal to u. Then h = 4u. Substituting these value in 2nd equation of motion with constant acceleration we get u = 18 m/s. We get v = -42 m/s from v = u + at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the initial velocity of the stone is not zero.

Comment: The phrase "left fall" means the stone is released from rest without any push

Comment: @pcforgeek: I believe it was "released from rest without any push" with respect to the balloon, not with respect to the ground.

Comment: @pcforgeek: At least if you assume that, you get the answer from your book.

Comment: You might be right as if we use 2 nd equation of motion in straight line with uniform acceleration then this answer should be right as we will get u = 18 m/s if u is initial velocity of stone relative to ground.